# How to get scrollYOffset on WebView in UWP?

Tags: webview, uwp, scrolltop

I tried this code on Visual studio. But it becomes :

> System.Exception: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020101'

How can I resolve it?

```
string function = @"window.external.notify(document.body.scrollTop)";

await PinView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { function });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> System.Exception: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020101'

Scripts in the web view content can use window.external.notify with a **`string`** parameter to send information back to your app. However, the type of `document.body.scrollTop` is `number`. So, you should convert the parameter to string.

```
string function = @"window.external.notify(document.body.scrollTop.toString())";
await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { function});
```

To receive these messages, handle the ScriptNotify event.

```
private void MyWebView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    MyText.Text = e.Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand. I tried this cord. But still alert "System.Exception: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020101'". I don't know why?

Comment: string function = @"window.external.notify(document.documentElement.scrollTop.toString())"; is wrong too.

Comment: Thank you very much! I solved this probrem. Before the page is rendered, running script becomes error. <WebView NavigationCompleted="Completed" ></WebView>  . After "Compleated" script runs well.